# Steam won't launch game in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: games, steam, 16.04

Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, using default open source drivers. I installed Magicka 2 on steam, but I cant' launch it. Trying to run`steam steam://rungameid/238370` I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
```

If i browse to the local files and launch it manually, it will start, but I can't play because it tells me I'm not connected to my steam account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [steam doesn't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761176/steam-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

try with this in your console

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam
```

In kubuntu 16.04 works for me