# Running Steam with terminal

Tags: games, steam

I had this problem trying to run steam on Ubuntu 16.04 and I got the problem solved with the solution provided here [steam doesn't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761176/steam-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04)

I noticed steam will shut down if I close terminal, so somehow the problem is not solved? how can I know the problem is solved and I can run steam normally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running programs in the background from terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal) -- *How do I run a program in the background of a shell, with the ability to close the shell while leaving the program running?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: you can `disown` the process so it won't die when its parent (the terminal session) gets killed, by changing your command slightly:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam & disown
```

**Option 2:** you can edit the .desktop file for Steam to make its launcher use the command you normally use, so you can start it by clicking the icon instead of launching Steam from a terminal.

Open a terminal and type

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

Make a backup copy of the `.desktop` file

```
sudo cp steam.desktop steam-bak
```

(you can restore the backup if needed by doing `mv steam-bak steam.desktop`) edit the original file:

```
sudo nano steam.desktop
```

find the first line that starts `Exec=` (you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to search in nano) and edit the line so it says:

```
Exec=bash -c "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam"
```

Save the file and exit (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)

Comment: altought your answer is very explanatory , I don't think it is working for me because I don't have steam on the desktop, it is on the side launcher ( sorry if I'm not making my point very clear, my english is poor and I'm new to ubuntu ).

Comment: hi @Jabu I'm sorry I should have said you need to open a terminal and enter those commands. This will modify the way the icon on the side launcher starts the program

Comment: first of all you don't have to be sorry, thanks for your time and your help. This worked out great! and I saw the whole code ( it is great for me because I'm starting to code also, lol) and that helped me understand a little bit more!