# Steam LIBGL problems

Tags: drivers, steam, c++, amd-graphics

Probably driver related. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 64bit on an AMD processor and graphics card. Trying to run steam with `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` gives me this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/grizeldi/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.8.so.1: symbol _ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.8.so.1: symbol _ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

On the same machine, on Ubuntu 15.10 32bit, steam failed to start but I solved it by removing libstdc++.so in steam runtime. I did the same on 64bit (before I got the same error than on 32bit), but now I get the error above.
Help?

EDIT: This did manage to get steam up and running: [Steam doesn't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761176/steam-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: So is your question resolved? If so, please close this question.

Comment: It works with a workaround (adding LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' before steam command), but I'd rather have a solution not workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with running of steam.

You need to execute lines below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will upgrade your libstdc++6:i386 and amd64 to libstdc++.so.6.0.22

After that you must execute:

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 $HOME/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

If the problem appeared again then just execute last command once again. It's working for me.