# I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 8.1, and am having trouble getting Steam to run

Tags: drivers, wine, games, steam

As the title says, I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside windows 8. When I run steam normally, I don't get a popup. In system monitor there is a process for each steam I open, but nothing happens. When I launch steam through terminal, I get

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/ben/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available 
(required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for 
appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I am able to run Windows games such as Super Hexagon through Wine, but I was told that Wine uses my windows graphics drivers. My graphics card is an AMD Radeon 8610g.

Edit: When I run sudo ubuntu-drivers devices, I get the following: driver : amd64-microcode - distro non-free

Comment: Wine doesn't use anything that's not in the system already. Dual boot or single OS is irrelevant, It won't use any Windows drivers. And the question or problem exactly? Those messages in terminal are... normal. Currently there are no alternative proprietary drivers rom that can be installed with the newer kernels. That's it, you already have a driver installed and running the best it can. Nothing else to do, move on.

Comment: What would be the ubuntu version I'd have to install?

Comment: Sorry, what? You started by saying *I just installed Ubuntu  16.10*. That's the current version...

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/761176/steam-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04/723696#723696 ... be sure to search past questions for `r600_dri.so` or `pcre_jit_stack_alloc`, for even more

Comment: @CelticWarrior ,The problem was with steam. I figured it. on my own.

Comment: @Phoen1x74, Could you post the solution you found as an answer.